# @font-face won't display custom fonts in WordPress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, fonts, font-face

I am attempting to add custom fonts to a WordPress site and I cannot get the correct font to display. I am able to get the custom font to display locally on an  HTML and CSS document I whipped up real quick and also by using the web developer tools in Firefox, so I know the font is loading. The font is called "Indubitably", I downloaded it from Font Squirrel and I am specifically testing with the .woff format.

Here is my code:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'indubitably';
    src: url('fonts/INDUBITA-webfont.woff');
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    color: black !important;
    font-family: 'indubitably' !important;
}
```

I think I've uploaded the font to the correct directory, which is /home/"myUsername"/html/wp-content/themes/hestia(my current theme)/fonts...

I've tried copying the code to style.css, I've used a plugin called Simple Custom CSS, I've also tried using the built-in WordPress CSS editor to no avail.

Sorry if this is a noob question, it is my first rodeo ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing the local path to your font with the complete URL, so change `fonts/INDUBITA-webfont.woff` to `http://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/hestia/fonts/INDUBITA-webfont.woff` (changing example.com to your correct domain, of course.

Comment: I know I tried this before and it didn't work but now it does... maybe I imagined it. Either way, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I'm a big fan of [transfonter](https://transfonter.org/)  which does all the heavy lifting in generating your font-face when given a font file. If you did do something wrong with your @font-face declaration, running it through this might amend them.

This is the kind of font-face it spits out:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Indubitably';
    src: url('../fonts/Indubitably.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('../fonts/Indubitably.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Other than that, I'd double check your `src` url.

Your styles live in `wp-content/themes/{project}/assets/css`, whilst your fonts live in `wp-content/themes/{project}/assets/fonts`.

Try `src: url('../fonts/INDUBITA-webfont.woff');`. `../` allows you to go back into the containing directory (in this case the `assets` folder`).

Comment: I tried your solution with no results. But I'm pretty sure my declaration is correct anyway, since it works in Firefox's web developer. Thanks for the response and the resource, it could come in handy in the future.

Comment: I think it could be the casing on the font-family. Try `font-family: 'Indubitably';`

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:** 
In one of the sections that the font doesn't affect first try to right-click and inspect elements. Second, in inspect page, you can see the source of font-family that affected and easily change it in the source file.

**Solution 2:** 
You can put static  in your header page in customizing theme

**Solution 3:** 
You can replace your specific font with the old one with the same name -> rename the new one name to old one name and put it into the fonts folder: wp-content/themes/hestia/fonts